# scikit-learn custom transformer throws NotFittedError from underlying model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to create my own scikit-learn transformer for encoding numerical features that contain a taxonomy, like zipcodes or industry codes (NAICS, MCC etc). In these kind of codes there is a structure: e.g. MCC 3000-3999 is 'travel and entertainment' which is broken down further into more granular categories like 'airlines', 'car rental' etc. We cannot use them as ordinal features but if we treat them as pure categorical features (e.g. by One-Hot-Encoding) we need to choose at which level of the code structure to apply the feature encoding.

To solve this I created my own scikit-learn transformer which is a variation of the [TargetEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.TargetEncoder.html) using a decision tree. The code is shown below. It's important to realize that during model training, out of sample decision tree regressor scores should be used to avoid overfitting. For that reason I implemented my own `fit_transform` function that produces these out of sample scores:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

class TaxonomyEncoder(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

def __init__(self, n_leafs=10, cv=3):
    self.n_leafs = n_leafs
    self.cv = cv

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    self.tree_ = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=self.n_leafs).fit(X,y)
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    return self.tree_.predict(X).reshape(-1,1)

def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
    self.tree_ = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=self.n_leafs)
    return cross_val_predict(self.tree_, X, y, cv=self.cv).reshape(-1,1)
```

The transformer works fine, except when using within a `ColumnTransformer`:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

transformer = ColumnTransformer([('taxonomy', TaxonomyEncoder(), ['mcc'])])
transformer.fit(df[['mcc']], df['y'])
transformer.transform(df[['mcc']])
```

Then I get the error that the decision tree is not fitted yet:

```
NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Apparently, scikit-learn does some checks below the surface that causes this error. Note that there is actually no reason to have a fitted decision tree as the tree is refitted within the `cross_val_predict` function. How can I solve this problem?

A fully working example to reproduce the error is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'mcc':[3000,3500,7339], 'y':[0,0,1]})

te = TaxonomyEncoder().fit(df[['mcc']], df['y'])
te.transform(df[['mcc']])
```

gives:

```
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [1.]])
```

and also fit_transform gives results as expected:

```
te.fit_transform(df[['mcc']], df['y'])

array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
```

But when wrapped in a ColumnTransformer, things go wrong:

```
transformer = ColumnTransformer([('taxonomy', TaxonomyEncoder(), ['mcc'])])
transformer.fit(df[['mcc']], df['y'])
transformer.transform(df[['mcc']])
```

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `fit_transform`, you need to fit the tree to the whole dataset in case you will later call `transform`. As written, you would also get an error trying

```py
te = TaxonomyEncoder()
te.fit_transform(df[['mcc']], df['y'])
te.transform(df[['mcc']])
```

The fix can be simple:

```py
def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
    self.fit(X, y)
    return cross_val_predict(self.tree_, X, y, cv=self.cv).reshape(-1,1)
```

---

The `ColumnTransformer` has a bit of a quirk that causes the error in using it: it actually always `fit_transform`s all of its transformers (even when just fitting the column transformer itself), in order to determine whether the outputs are sparse and thus whether the hstack should be sparse.

Comment: @Frits What's inelegant? It's the same number of lines, and more DRY.

Comment: the decision tree is fitted but that fitting is not used when producing out-of-sample predictions in `cross_val_predict` right?

Comment: @Frits Correct, because `cross_val_predict` clones the estimator before fitting to each fold. (And you need the estimator fitted to the entire training data for future transformations, hence the error.)